# How to get the same value of AVG() on both aggregated & non-aggregated dataset

Tags: sql, math, amazon-athena, presto

We have a large data table that was being used to return total average price, however this and other queries were taking so long to process that we have aggragated the results by country and day.

This is an example of the original table:

```
Country   |  code | Price | Date 
--------------------------------------
IND       |  XXZ  | 7.435 | 2021-01-01
IND       |  XSZ  | 7.445 | 2021-01-01
IND       |  XAZ  | 6.435 | 2021-01-01
USA       |  XYN  | 2.524 | 2021-01-02
USA       |  AYD  | 9.524 | 2021-01-02
USA       |  XYD  | 2.534 | 2021-01-02
AUS       |  YYB  | 1.819 | 2021-01-03
AUS       |  YSB  | 4.319 | 2021-01-03
--------------------------------------
                 AVG(Price) = 5.254375
```

```
SELECT AVG(Price) from table
```

Results in `5.254375`

To optimise all queries against this recordset, we aggregate the table using this expression:

```
SELECT country,sum(price),Avg(price),date 
FROM table 
GROUP BY country,date
```

```
Country |  sum(Price)| AVG(Price) | Date 
----------------------------------------------
IND     |  21.315    | 7.105      | 2021-01-01
USA     |  14.582    | 4.86066667 | 2021-01-02
AUS     |  1.638     | 3.069      | 2021-01-03
-----------------------------------------------
                   Avg = 5.011555557
```

> When I take the `Avg(Avg(Price)) = 5.011555557`, this value doesn't match with the AVG(Price) = 5.254375  on non-aggregated data.

However now in the report, we still want to be able to show the correct average figure, but we cannot use the original table because thee query takes too long to process.

How can we calculate the overall average price, only using this aggregated record set?

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add **only** one tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: Is this because you want to select? AVG() is usually enough, the issue is that in the aggregated set you can't determine how many rows were involved, or rather how many were excluded.

Comment: more background on why you need this will help

Comment: @ChrisSchaller currently, we have a non-aggregated dataset in our system that has a huge no of rows that affect the performance. so plan to reduce the row with aggregated value. But this will cause an issue on AVG() function

Comment: Just use separate DB query that only reads avg and not lines

Comment: Ok @RajeshA I see your issue, I've updated my answer with a fiddle to prove it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really so much to do with SQL, but simple math.

You need to use the original *count* to rebuild to correct `TOTAL/COUNT` expression.

We can calculate that from the total, it is highly subject to rounding errors, but it gets close, ideally, if this is super important to you, then you should record the original count.

```
SELECT country, sum(price), Avg(price), Count(1), date 
FROM table GROUP BY by country, date
```

| Country | sum(Price) | AVG(Price) | Count | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| IND | 21.315 | 7.105 | 3 | 2021-01-01 |
| USA | 14.582 | 4.86066667 | 3 | 2021-01-02 |
| AUS | 1.638 | 3.069 | 2 | 2021-01-03 |

Or we can re-construct the count:

```
SELECT Country, totalPrice, avePrice, totalPrice/avePrice, Date
FROM AggregatedValues
```

_results the same table as above.

But we can't just use AVG, because that uses the number of rows in the result, instead we should evaluate the average ourselves:

```
SELECT SUM(sumPrice) / SUM(sumPrice/avePrice) FROM AggregatedValues
```

Or is you had stored the *count*:

```
SELECT SUM(sumPrice) / SUM(Count) FROM AggregatedValues
```

Check this out in sql fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/818872/7

I see your date column in that dataset, so we can still rollup the aggregated values using group by over the date:

```
SELECT date, SUM(sumPrice) / SUM(sumPrice/avePrice) 
FROM AggregatedValues
GROUP BY date;
```

| date | Ave |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01T00:00:00Z | 5.254376 |

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/818872/9

Now ultimately, the average is not the figure of `5.254375` you were expecting, this is due to loss of precision when you store the aggregated value, if you had stored the original count though, we get as close as we can get:

### Updated fiddle, my original example lost precision!

But that also highlighted how this type of reverse average can never be as accurate as using the original set!

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/27e7c/1

```
SELECT date, SUM(sumPrice) / SUM([count]) 
FROM AggregatedValues
GROUP BY date;
```

| date | Ave |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01T00:00:00Z | 5.254375 |

Comment: It would work if there were same number of records for each country

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options

A: Use another query that only gets average and doesn't return lines

B: Get sum of all prices per country and count of records per country. Then you can get avg by dividing total of all price sums with all record count

Comment: how can we apply option B, when we have a different date in the same country

Comment: @RajeshA That works same way that having multiple countries does. Just get sum of all sums  and sum of all counts and divide them. Though I'd suggest going with option A.